# "all of that" instead of "all of which"

Tags: relative-pronouns, that-vs-which

The following is an excerpt from [the website](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clauses-7.html).

> Disneyland, **all of which** belongs to the Disney Company, is located in Anaheim.

While I am aware of "all of which", "some of which", etc. usages, I think I've never heard of "all of that".

> Disneyland, **all of that** belongs to the Disney Company, is located in Anaheim.

I believe the second sentence is grammatically wrong. A thought occured to me that it may be related to the nonrestrictive usage of relative pronoun. "That" cannot be used as nonrestrictive one.(after comma)

Can anyone please verify this?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: You are right, "that" is not possible in that function. Which is one of the reasons why "that" is not a relative pronoun, but a clause subordinator.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you for your helpful comment! Can you please elaborate more on a "clause subordinator"?

Comment: The word "that" which introduces relative clauses is not actually a relative pronoun but a subordinator, just as it is when it introduces content clauses as in _I realise that you felt insulted_. This is evident from several factors; for example it has no genitive form and it cannot occur as complement of a preposition. It is not possible to say *_the woman that's turn it was_ (instead you have to say _the woman whose turn it was_). And you can't say _*The letter to that you referred_ (instead you have to say _the letter to which you referred_.)

Comment: @BillJ I tried to understand your explanation with my background in grammar, which was learned outside English-speaking countries. Here is my interpretation: a "subordinator" means that when "that" is followed by a perfect sentence, introducing a noun clause; as a "relative pronoun", "that" is followed by an incomplete sentence(lacking subject or object), introducing an adjective clause. As you said, if "that" in "all of that" is a subordinator, the sentence is wrong becuase it is replacing part of the subject.

Comment: But I am still not sure why "that" in "all of that" cannot be a relative pronoun. I might be misunderstood, but for me it seems like since "all of that" plays out as a subject, "that" looks like a relative pronoun.

Comment: No: in _Disneyland, all of that belongs to the Disney Company ..._, "that" is not a relative pronoun, so _all of that belongs to the Disney Company_ is not a valid relative clause because it is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are correct in this context.  Personally, I think the "all of which" is too much and in actual communication you would just say:

> Disneyland, owned by the Disney Corporation, is located in Anaheim.

But I get that site is just offering examples using "all of which".  "All of that" is not grammatically incorrect, though.  *That* is a generic pronoun which, in this use, would refer to some previously mentioned subject.

> (After reading a long book) It took a long time, but I'm glad I read *all of that*.
>
> (Looking over an area of new houses) *All of that* was built in the last three years.
>
> Less stringent environmental controls leads to increased pollution in Asia, and *all of that* eventually turns into smog over parts of North America.

Of course, in the third sentence, you could more efficiently say

> "... Asia, *all of which* eventually turns into smog ..."

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! So, "that" does not play a role as a relative pronoun (which serves as conjunction+pronoun). Am I correctly understoond?

Comment: @Luxembourg , BillJ says here it's a "clause subordinator", meaning it helps join two clauses together.  I don't quite understand the subtle distinction between a "relative pronoun" and a "clause subordinator" since in my examples "that" definitely *acts* as a pronoun.

Comment: I was referring only to the "that" which introduces relative clauses (see my message to the OP). The "that" in your examples is of course a pronoun used anaphorically.